# Variable Showing Nil After Checking for Nil When Downloading Image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-storage

Bear with me as I explain this,

I am making a chat room in which users are able to upload photos for others to see. When the user hits an icon they are able to upload the photo to my Firebase Database (this is happening successfully and I have tested this already). The photo's URL is being passed into the messages database and loaded into the table view which I have created (I know the photo URL is there because of print statements and checking the database). However, when I go to download the photo from the URL, the app crashes saying that it found nil when unwrapping my optional (imageData) - this comes inside of an if statement which I only supposed to execute after checking that the imageData is not nil. I also have a print statement before this if statement which confirms that the data is not nil. Why is it finding nil upon unwrapping the data? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
let notificationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageImageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageCellForPhotos

        notificationCell.clipsToBounds = true
        let newPhotoURL = NSURL(string: messagesArray[indexPath.row].userSentImage)! as URL

        print("\(newPhotoURL) Hello World This Time")

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: newPhotoURL) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                print(imageData)

                if imageData != nil {
                    notificationCell.sentImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                }

            }
        }

        return notificationCell
```

Comment: Can you show me the actual crash log

Comment: post the complete log

Comment: xcode console..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the issue, I have found the problem. When I created my notification cell (using the xib file) I linked up the uiimageview to the view controller for the cell. However, somehow the image view got unlinked from the cell. So when the program went to upload the image to the image view, it was finding nil for the image view rather than finding nil for the image itself (i.e. the image view apparently didn't exist). This was such a silly problem. Thanks for helping me investigate. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't force wrap  in your code  don't use ! it cause a-lot of crashes

use `if let or guard`

so  `newPhotoURL`

```
 guard let newPhotoURL =  NSURL(string: messagesArray[indexPath.row].userSentImage) as? URL else {return}
```

and  `imageData`

```
if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: newPhotoURL) , let image = UIImage(data: imageData)  {
        notificationCell.sentImageView.image = image
    }
```

Comment: where is podfile

Comment: how to enter ChooseClassController from camera or from which button

Comment: i don't get any crash i already sign in and get me image at class

Comment: in this class class ChooseClassController

Answer (score 0):

You are try to convert image from data which is not retrieve completely so please use below library which will give you better result to retrieve asynchronously via url.

[Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

Comment: Why there is a need of library?

Comment: Because it will help to cache data.